# But you got to make me change my mind. - what usage of "get" is this?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

I am trying to understand the usage of the "get" in the sentence:

> But you got to make me change my mind.

I guess it is not "have got".

Comment: It's an odd sentence. It's most likely 'have got' as you suggest, but why would you say that someone has to make you change your mind? Alternatively, you could be saying that someone was privileged enough to make you change your mind… which is perhaps a teensy bit less strange of a thing to be saying, but still quite odd.

Comment: I read it as 'have got' as well (with the 'have' elided as it often is when contracted in informal speech), in the sense that the subject needs to be substantially persuaded if they're going to change their opinion.

Comment: The "got to V" seems to have a meaning of obligation or necessity, similar to that of the idiom "have got". There's also the similar examples: *"But you got to.", "You got to do it."* This kind of stuff is common in my dialect. Hopefully someone will post a detailed explanation of what is actually going on. (Perhaps it is merely an informal dropping of "have" from the idiom usage of "have got".)

Comment: There's a bit in the 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*, in section 3.45, footnote 'e', on page 142: "In informal speech, the first word of *HAVE got to* and *had better* is often completely elided, . . ."

Answer (score 1):

To give some context, I found that the OP's quote may be coming from one of [Tracy Chapman's lyrics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa5BfgJWb3o)?

```
TRACY CHAPMAN LYRICS
"Give Me One Reason"

Give me one reason to stay here
And I'll turn right back around
Give me one reason to stay here
And I'll turn right back around
Because I don't want leave you lonely
**But you got to make me change my mind**
```

The answer that follows should be credited to @F.E., who wrote in the comments:

> There's a bit in the 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al., A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, in section 3.45, footnote 'e', on page 142: "In informal speech, the first word of HAVE got to and had better is often completely elided, . . ."

Unfortunately, none of the grammar books I own deal with `have got to` at a great length. The most detailed description I have found is on the [BBC's Learning English site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv127.shtml).

`must`, `have to`, and `have got to` are modal and semi-modals verbs that express personal obligation. `have to` and `have got to` are preferred in conversation, with `have got to` being considered very informal. Thus, it is not surprising that in this informal cases of use, the first word of `have got` is often elided as described by Quirk *et al.*

Comment: +1 for finding the lyrics which have the OP's example in it. :) Hopefully you'll update your answer so that it discusses the idiom "*have got*" (as often used in "have got to V").

Comment: @F.E., actually I haven't realised that was the construct until you mentioned. Please, go ahead and put all your comments together into an answer, so that you can get the credit.

Comment: I'm too lazy, and it's way past my bedtime. I had posted two quick comments onto the OP's main post, so that info (and maybe also the internet) might be enough for you to do your edit.

Answer (score 1):

One view might be that it is just a clumsy way of saying 'You made me change my mind'.

But as 'got' becomes the main verb and 'to make me change my mind' a predicate phrase, it stresses an achievement on your part, that you were able to make me change my mind.

There are, however, in my view, better ways of saying it e.g. 'You persuaded me to change my mind'.

Comment: Thanks but what usage of GET would that be (in Oxford dictionary).

Comment: Assuming that this sentence is by a native speaker, I don't think this interpretation is correct.  Using *get* as a synonym for *attain* in this context is very awkward and unidiomatic.

Comment: @MunchyWilly It sounds perfectly idiomatic for an American. (It is not a form you would hear in Britain.) 'You got to go to China' i.e. you got the opportunity and were able to go to China. 'You got to make me change my mind, so that you were able to go to China'.

Comment: @WS So you say it is "get to" - to have an opportunity? Also "You had the opportunity to change my mind"?

Comment: @SDand Past tense. Of course it could mean something quite different if there is a missing 'have', as is  frequently the case in lazy speech. 'You gotta make me change my mind'. i.e. You must make me change my mind.

Comment: @WS2 What's unidiomatic to my American ears is the context in which it's used... 'getting an opportunity to change someone else's mind' is not only a weird idea, couching it in these terms is weirder still.  Weird enough that I can't imagine a native speaker ever saying this with your proposed meaning.  An elided contracted 'have' is *much* more plausible.

Comment: @MunchyWilly I agree that it is a rather odd sounding sentence. The only alternative is that there is a 'have' missing. 'You have got to make me change my mind', which means something completely different, is grammatical.